# Updating a column with the earliest date which has the same identifier, and has a column > 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database which, simiplified, is as follows :

```
ID  |  SecondID   |  DateRecorded  |  NumberToCheck  |  NumberToUpdate
```

`NumberToUpdate` currently has a value for 0 for all rows.

I wish to update `NumberToUpdate` with the value for `NumberToCheck` on the same row, MINUS the value for `NumberToCheck`  which has the earliest `DateRecorded` "`(Min(DateRecorded)`" where `NumberToCheck` is greater than 0, and which has the same ID and secondID as the original row.

So far I have

```
UPDATE dbo.Table
SET NumberToUpdate =//Update NumberToUpdate
   NumberToCheck - //NumberToCheck from the current row, subtracting...
      (SELECT TOP 1 t2.NumberToCheck FROM Table t2 WHERE ID = t2.ID AND secondID = t2.secondID AND t2.DateRecorded = 
      (SELECT TOP 1 MIN(t3.DateRecorded) FROM Table t3  WHERE t2.ID = t3.ID AND t2.secondID = t3.secondID AND t3.Passes > 0))
      //the NumberToCheck with the earliest date, of the same ID.
```

This is not correct however, and is returning me values which make no sense (including minus values of which there shouldn't be any!)

What have I forgotten here?

Thanks very much

Comment: 1st guess: if you are taking the first NumbertoCheck that is non-zero and subracting it from some earlier rows that have a zero value, you would probably get some negative numbers. You might mean to NOT update those.

Comment: No, there would be no negative values as the number is cumulative :)

Comment: Update : I have now added another column to my example, which makes it more difficult. I need to match up with both the ID and the SecondID in my update. So far none of the answers have worked correctly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should start with a select query to get the value you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from table t
      where number_to_check > 0
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Now, you can use this in your original update:

```
with vals as (select t.*
              from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
                    from table t
                    where NumberToCheck > 0
                   ) t
              where seqnum = 1
             )
update table
    set NumberToUpdate = NumberToCheck - vals.NumberToCheck
from vals
where t.id = vals.id
```

Comment: This returns invalid object name t when replaced with the relevant details of my database. I have also now updated the question slightly.

Comment: I used the name "t" instead of "table".  That said, naming a table "table" is a bad idea.  First, "table" is a reserved word in SQL, and you want to avoid using reserved words for table and column names.  Second, you should be able to find a less generatic name than table.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dbo.Table as t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MIN(DateRecord) as mindate, ID
  FROM dbo.Table
  GROUP BY ID
) as mindates
ON t1.ID = mindates.ID
INNER JOIN
dbo.Table as substractions
ON mindates.mindate = substraction.DateRecord
AND mindates.ID = substraction.ID
SET t1.numberToUpdate = t1.numberToCheck - substractions.NumberToCheck
WHERE substraction.NumberToCheck > 0
--your questions is ambigious here: did you mean this one should be greater than 0, or should t1.NumberToCheck > 0 ?
AND t1.DateRecord <> mindates.mindate
--Assuming that you don't want to update the record with the lowest date.
```

Note:
This assumes that DateRecord combined with ID is unique, which isn't guaranteed by your structure. I'm afraid that with this table layout, there is no other way.

Comment: This will not work due to syntax error, I believe you cannot have an AS in an update statement ?

Comment: And DateRecord combined with ID should be unique, yes :) t1.NumberToCheck should be > 0 also :)